# What do I need to develop higher grade weapons?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In the development section it seems I am missing some weapons even if I have the blueprints for them.

For example I have grade 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 of M2000-NL, but I cannot develop grade 6. The slot is missing. What can I do to develop grade 6?

So the question is: what do I need to develop higher grade weapons?

---

This is the weapon I would like to research:
[image]

And these are the levels of my staff units:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there is no grade 7 M2000-NL. If you follow the line going right through the screen, you'll find the grade 8 version waiting to be developed.